# Javascript array of arrays query

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am using highcharts.js to plot a simple column graph using my json data, I have done this before but now I'm plotting with a slightly different dataset (filtered and different format)

For "processed_json", idea used : http://codeinjs.blogspot.com/2013/07/preprocess-json-data-to-use-in.html

Currently, my processed_json is :

```
function plotgraph1(filter1)
        {
            var processed_json = new Array();

            $j.map(filter1, function(obj, i) {
             processed_json.push(obj[0], obj[1]);
             console.log(processed_json)    

            }); 
...................
         }
```

Console prints :

```
["2014-06-14T18:30:00Z", 4044,
 "2014-06-15T18:30:00Z", 5030,
 "2014-06-16T18:30:00Z", 4913,
 "2014-06-17T18:30:00Z", 4985,
 "2014-06-18T18:30:00Z", 4778,
 "2014-06-19T18:30:00Z", 4733,
 "2014-06-20T18:30:00Z", 3960,
 "2014-06-21T18:30:00Z", 4221,  .......]
```

Opening up gives :

```
0: "2014-06-14T18:30:00Z"
1: 4044
2: "2014-06-15T18:30:00Z"
3: 5030
4: "2014-06-16T18:30:00Z"
5: 4913
```

.......... and so on

It is storing the date1, metric1 and so on, but I want it to store it in different arrays. 
Basically, it should be an array of arrays, for each day, a separate array.
So that highcharts.js can read it properly.
Now it's reading the data but, since all dates are in one array it's skipping a date and showing 28 dates instead of 14 days (which is the selected range); (double basically)

Earlier and correct "processed_json" is :

```
[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
0: Array[2]
0: "2014-04-30T18:30:00Z"
1: 200303
```

I was trying something like this :

```
var processed_json1 = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < processed_json.length; i++)
            {
            processed_json1.push(processed_json[i]);
            }
```

But, clearly this is wrong and I am wasting too much time. Any good direction/suggestion will be highly appreciated to convert my data format to the correct one for highcharts to read it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving multiple arguments to `push` is just short for calling `push` separately with each argument, it doesn't collect them together in an array. You need to make them an object first:

```
function plotgraph1(filter1)
{
    var processed_json = $j.each(filter1, function(i, obj) {
        processed_json.push([obj[0], obj[1]]);  

    }); 
    console.log(processed_json)
    ...................
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c3TRx/3/)

Comment: Yes, the array is defined at first by me also. Usig $j.each gives me an "undefined" array completely. What's wrong here?

Comment: The arguments to the iteration function for `$.each` are in the opposite order. However, I just changed it to use `$.map` and use the return value.

Comment: So I just used this, and it gave me the exact same thing I am printing, graph is plotted but console has same format as posted in my problem (ie. date,metric,date,metric and so on) 
So I tried this  : return [{"date":obj[0]}, {"metric":obj[1]}];

This gives in console : 0: Object
date: "2014-06-14T18:30:00Z"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
metric: 4044
__proto__: Object
2: Object
date: "2014-06-15T18:30:00Z"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
metric: 5030
__proto__: Object

This is better, but I need date and metric (corresponding) in one object, then 2nd object with date and metric together and so on

Comment: I've changed my answer to return an object.

Comment: You can't return two things in one `return` call. `return {blah1}, {blah2}` is the same as just `return {blah2}` because of the way the comma operator works.

Comment: Barmar, this did the trick I am getting both date and metric together in one object. But the charts are not coming still and I just checked back, it needs to be an array ( not an object!) I'm really sorry for irritating. But if you could just convert this to an array, this would be solved I think. Thanks a lot anyways !

Comment: But, whenever I convert this to array using push, the date and metric separate out as two different parts! How do I make them come inside one array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57452/discussion-between-user2063493-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
            var array = [];
        for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
            array.push({"date":"metric"});
        }
        console.log(array);
```

Outputs:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
date: "metric"
1: Object
date: "metric"
2: Object
```

Comment: So I replaced my line with this now :  
processed_json.push({"date":obj[0]}, {"metric":obj[1]});

And i'm getting objects in console finally but each object has one date/metric only. I want date and metric corresponding in each object. Eg : 0: Object
date: "2014-06-14T18:30:00Z"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
metric: 4044
__proto__: Object

What more changes do I make?

Comment: @user2063493 , obj[0] never changes value, you need to use your loop iterator. If obj[] contains all of your information and it is structured date,metric,date,metric,date,metric a loop with obj[i],obj[i+1] should work.

Comment: As I said before, this is almost doing my job with this in console : 20: Object
date: "2014-06-24T18:30:00Z"
__proto__: Object
21: Object
metric: 4847
__proto__: Object
22: Object
date: "2014-06-25T18:30:00Z"
__proto__: Object
23: Object
metric: 4419
__proto__: Object

But, I need corresponding date and metric inside one object and together and am unable to do so. Filter has many more arguments, so obj[i] and obj[i+1] will not work, just tried.

Only small tweaking is needed now, still not able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
processed_json.reduce(function(soFar, val, idx) {
    if (idx % 2 == 0) {soFar.push([]);} 
    soFar[soFar.length - 1].push(val); 
    return soFar;
}, []); 
//=> [["2014-06-14T18:30:00Z", 4044], ["2014-06-15T18:30:00Z", 5030], ...]
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I think this is it, can you pls clarify what I should write instead of "soFar", "val" and idx" . Also, do I completely remove my $j.map code and then use your code?

Comment: The only data in this is the initial `processed_json`.  The others are internal features of `reduce`.  It was just the most concise way I thought of to take your list and turn it into a list of two-element lists.

Comment: This may not really be what you want.  I think I read the original too quickly.  This converts ["2014-06-14T18:30:00Z", 4044, "2014-06-15T18:30:00Z", 5030, ...] into [["2014-06-14T18:30:00Z", 4044],
["2014-06-15T18:30:00Z", 5030], ...].  There's probably a simpler approach.